# WPF - How to run WPF solution in VS2010 SP1

Tags: wpf

I am following the tutorial from the book "Pro C# 2010 and the .NET 4 Platform". After I load the sample code from MyXamlPad project under Chapter 27 and try to run it, I got an error from the compiler as follows:

```
Error   1   The "GenerateResource" task failed unexpectedly.
System.DllNotFoundException: Unable to load DLL 'FileTracker.dll': A dynamic link library (DLL) initialization routine failed. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007045A)
   at Microsoft.Build.Shared.NativeMethodsShared.InprocTracking.StartTrackingContextWithRoot(String intermediateDirectory, String taskName, String rootMarker)
   at Microsoft.Build.Utilities.FileTracker.StartTrackingContextWithRoot(String intermediateDirectory, String taskName, String rootMarkerResponseFile)
   at Microsoft.Build.Tasks.GenerateResource.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   at Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.ExecuteInstantiatedTask(ITaskExecutionHost taskExecutionHost, TaskLoggingContext taskLoggingContext, TaskHost taskHost, ItemBucket bucket, TaskExecutionMode howToExecuteTask, Boolean& taskResult)   MyXamlPad


Reference:

http://www.apress.com/9781430225492
http://www.apress.com/downloadable/download/sample/sample_id/12/
```

What should I do to fix this problem? Or I just cannot run the WPF inside VS2010 and have to use the MSBUILD instead.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make sure you have only one v4.0*** folder (you can rename if you don't wish to delete) in your C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework folder. That should do the trick.

If you already have only one of these v4.0*** folders you can try editing the Microsoft.Common.targets file within that folder and removing         TrackFileAccess="$(TrackFileAccess)" and TrackerLogDirectory="$(TrackerLogDirectory)" entries from the  GenerateResource node around line 1850.

Comment: it works for me know. May you give me a little background what's going here? Does it mean that my client has to do the same thing in order to use it? --Thank you

Comment: There could be some problem of running the sample itself. By default, WPF project in VS 2010 is using .NET 4.0 Client Profile. The sample used can be different in .NET version.

Comment: For the record I had to close and reopen VS2010 for this change to take effect. Thought I'd save the next guy some confusion.

Answer (score 2):

I have posted my comment above, and I'll add more details in this answer.

There could be some problem of running the sample itself. By default, WPF project in VS 2010 is using .NET 4.0 Client Profile. The sample used can be different in .NET version.

Have you tried to rebuild the solution? If it still doesn't work, try adding the assembly reference manually to the sample WPF project.

Comment: @eriawan, the solution provided by kzen works for me. However, I don't know why that problem happens and also I don't know what the theory behind that fix?

Comment: There are some theories behind that fix, because it's so rare to happen. First: it can be you're developing on 64bit machine (such as Windows 7 x64) and .NET will be installed in 64bit folder but the project will search the 32bit .NET assemblies. Second: it could be you're using the .NET Client profile. Third: it can be you have applied .NET 4 SP1.

Comment: @eriawan, My machine spec is WinXP SP3+VS2010SP1+.NET 4.0 SP1. May you give me the official resource that targets this issue? -- thx

Comment: which windows XP do you have? 32bit or x64?

Comment: Have you already cleared the assembly reference and adding them manually? In my machine, it works.