# WPF -- when does C# Compiler of VS2010 start to support to compile XAML markup?

Tags: wpf

Based on the book "Pro C# 2010 and the .net 4.0 platform" page page 1148, it claims that C# compiler doesn't understand XAML markup. Instead, we have to use MSBUILD.

However, I found that I could be able to directly compile the WPF solution within VS2010 SP1 with the help from

[WPF - How to run WPF solution in VS2010 SP1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6117576/wpf-how-to-run-wpf-solution-in-vs2010-sp1)

So, the question is that "when does C# Compiler of VS2010 start to support to compile XAML markup?"

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

XAML has nothing to do with C#; it wouldn't make sense for the C# compiler to support XAML.

Visual Studio has used MSBuild since 2005; `.csproj` files are actually MSBuild scripts.

Answer (score 3):

C# compiler doesn't compile XAML since it is a different language. However, when building a WPF application, the XAML-markup is compiled into code by Visual Studio. For more information, see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa970678.aspx